# Miltiple if codes dont work together? (php)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a series of if codes that need to be put together but the code acts weird and chooses the last if code.

```
if($boardid='1'){ $altboard='13' and $title='Archives' ;}
elseif($boardid='2'){ $altboard='14' and $title='Archives' ;}
```

so this code turns out to work, but it cant be repeated to finish the rest of the codes

the code that doesn't work is:

```
if($boardid=='1'){ $altboard='13' and $title='Archives' ;}
if($boardid='2'){ $altboard='14' and $title='Archives' ;}
if($boardid='3'){ $altboard='15' and $title='Archives' ;}
if($boardid='6'){ $altboard='16' and $title='Archives' ;}
if($boardid='7'){ $altboard='17' and $title='Archives' ;}
```

and there is more if codes to add, but i didn't add them, as it only uses whatever turns out to be the last of the lines  regardless of boards, even though it clearly recognizes the boards. so what gives and how do i make a series of if codes work together? I have another file with the exact same thing and it reacts the same. If then elseif for the rest of the code doesn't work and neither does alternating if and else if.

putting two  equal signs Works fine with The above mentioned code but not with the second mentioned code which is this

```
    if($wrong=='0'){$prize='1000';}
    if($wrong=='1'){$prize='700';}
    if($wrong=='2'){$prize='500';}
    if($wrong=='4'){$prize='200';}
    if($wrong=='5'){$prize='100';}
```

Unlike the last one where it keeps only the last code this one takes only the first one. so the prize always turns out to be 1000. any help here

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `and`?

Comment: In second case, I think you are comparing string with integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be like

```
if($boardid=='1'){ $altboard='13'; $title='Archives';}
if($boardid=='2'){ $altboard='14'; $title='Archives';}
if($boardid=='3'){ $altboard='15'; $title='Archives';}
if($boardid=='6'){ $altboard='16'; $title='Archives';}
if($boardid=='7'){ $altboard='17'; $title='Archives';}
```

Answer (score 3):

You’re using `=` rather than `==` in your `if` conditions, which, supposing the value you assign is truthy, will always be true. Change your conditions to use `==` for comparison.

That said, you might want to consider using an associative array:

```
$data = array(
    '1' => array('altboard' => '13', 'title' => 'Archives'),
    '2' => array('altboard' => '14', 'title' => 'Archives'),
    // ...
);
if(array_key_exists($data, $boardid)) {
    $altboard = $data[$boardid]['altboard'];
    $title = $data[$boardid]['title'];
}
```

Or, if the title is always “Archives”, pull that out:

```
$altboard_map = array('1' => '13', '2' => '14', /* ... */);
if(array_key_exists($data, $boardid)) {
    $title = "Archives";  // consider moving out of the 'if' if applicable
    $altboard = $altboard_map[$boardid]['altboard'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use switch case :

```
$title='Archives';
switch ($boardid) {
    case 1:
        $altboard='13';
        break;
    case 2:
        $altboard='14';
        break;
    case 3:
        $altboard='15';
        break;
    case 6:
        $altboard='16';
        break;
    case 7:
        $altboard='17';
        break;
}
```